# count of unique users for min date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in a single table structured like so:

| device type | userID | createdDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | jpq | 2018-01-01 |
| A | xyz | 2020-01-01 |
| B | abc | 2020-01-01 |
| C | abc | 1999-01-01 |

I'm trying to find - for each devicetype, how many users have that devicetype as their oldest entry in the database.

My output should look like this for the example data:

| count of users | device type |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | A |
| 1 | C |

The query I have so far looks like this, but it also returns a min(createdDate) and I'm not confident that it's getting the count correctly.

```
SELECT
    count(d.UserId),
    d.deviceType,
    min(d.CreationDate)
FROM Device d
GROUP BY d.deviceType
```

Comment: It's not; it's giving you the `MIN` and the `COUNT` separately. You first need to filter to the minimum date, and *then* `COUNT`.

Comment: Though I don't udnerstand your expected results. Shouldn't it be `1` for each?

Comment: Please add something like `A, "abc", 2018-01-01` to your data set and adjust the desired result.

Comment: if you want the devices  minum date, wouldn't there be the comut always 1, and why os in your example B excluded

Comment: @nbk no, for each unique device I want a count of how many users have that as their oldest device.

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you try to get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to get appropriate rows by using row number for each user and then get your result, like this:

```sql
SELECT
    count(d.UserId),
    d.deviceType
FROM (
    SELECT
      userId,
      deviceType,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY createdDate) rw
    FROM Device
) d
WHERE d.rw = 1
GROUP BY
  d.deviceType
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed and demonstrates some techniques I've yet to learn. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Its working great answer with brief description. Thank you!